# Can not pass the action get param to the PHP file

Tags: php, smarty

I have a smarty project, and in the `.tpl` file, there is a form:

```
<form method="get" action="{$smarty.server.PHP_SELF}?action=func1">
    <input type="text" name="username"/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

there is a question, if the php file have many function for different action requests, so in the template if have many forms, I want to through the `action` for distinguish.

but in my practice, see upper code, I write like this, this can not delivery the `action` to my php file.

I want to write the `action` in the form action, because this can be more standard. so I don't want to write it in a hidden input. why write in the action can not pass into the php file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use submit button with specified name and value:

```
<form method="get" action="{$smarty.server.PHP_SELF}">
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="func1" />
</form>
```

and then you'll get a global variable $_POST['action'] with value func1. But the value will be showing on your button title, so I offer you to find forms only by submit name, for example name='submit_form1'.

Comment: do you mean `$_GET['action'] `?

Comment: Form method is a "get", you will not get anything with $_POST['action']

Comment: @sof-03, no, it will be $_POST data like the `username` variable.

Comment: but if set like this, the value='func1', how to set the input button text replace of the value?

Comment: You can't. but you can find a form just by a button name, for example: `if(isset($_POST['submit_button_form1'])) { # ...  }` and no matter what value this variable contains.